# Replace values in sympy NDimArray

Tags: sympy

I would like to replace values in a sympy NDimArray.

I have the following code

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
e = sp.MatrixSymbol('e',3,3)
E = sp.Matrix(e)

# Make E symmetric
E[1,0] = E[0,1] 
E[2,0] = E[0,2]
E[2,1] = E[1,2]

result = sp.tensorproduct(E,E)

E_tst = np.random.rand(3,3)
E_tst[1,0] = E_tst[0,1] 
E_tst[2,0] = E_tst[0,2]
E_tst[2,1] = E_tst[1,2]
resultNumeric = np.tensordot(E_tst,E_tst,axes=0)

check = resultNumeric - result.as_mutable().subs({E:sym.Matrix(E_tst)})
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'MutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'subs'`.

How can I replace the symbols in a NDimArray?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `MutableDenseNDimArray` doesn't inherit from `Basic`, whereas `ImmutableDenseNDimArray` does, therefore some attributes are not available. Don't ask me about this design decision.

However, you can achieve the same result by creating a substitution dictionary:

```
# substitution dictionary
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(list(E), list(Matrix(E_tst)))}
check = resultNumeric - result.subs(d)
```

Comment: Oh... Ok, I guess. So I can just do : `check = resultNumeric - result.subs({E[0,0]:E_tst[0,0],
 E[0,1]:E_tst[0,1],
 E[0,2]:E_tst[0,2],
 E[1,1]:E_tst[1,1],
 E[1,2]:E_tst[1,2],
 E[2,2]:E_tst[2,2]})`, no?

Comment: yes, it's the same!